# Tiddlywiki alternative

Tags: wiki, tiddlywiki, tiddlywiki5

I found TiddlyWiki recently and was very pleased to find its approach in many ways very much in line with what I want from a note-taking/documenting/productivity system:

- the idea of splitting content into smaller "tiddlers" instead of whole documents
- treating these tiddlers as data not

  - ability to add "fields" (attributes) to tiddlers
  - ability to select tiddlers with a
- easy extensibility with macros, inline javascript and plugins

However

1. tiddlywiki doesn't have built-in versioning in the style of mediawiki
2. tiddlywiki is built as a single-page application (HTmL file, no server) and saves data locally, not allowing

Point 1 is a real shame. I can do commit my tiddlywiki files to a git repo but it is not quite as convenient.

It is possible to solve 2 to some extent with a plugin (https://github.com/OokTech/TW5-Bob)- something that attests to how well implemented tiddlywiki is. However, it doesn't quite give everything I'd like from a multi-user wiki: there are no separate user logins for instance.

After using Tiddlywiki with the Bob nukti-user plugin for a bit and loosing a load of work, I'm looking for something that has some of the same approach as tiddlyWiki but has a built-in serer component, multi-user editing and ideally also content versioning.

Does anyone have any suggestion?

I am ucrrently looking at TWiki, decko, MoinMoin, DokuWiki, FosWiki, MediaWiki, XWiki.

Comment: Unfortunately, this kind of question is off-topic at SO, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic . Also you are not completing your sentences which makes it difficult to help you ("treating these tiddlers as data not ???", "ability to select tiddlers with a ???", "tiddlywiki is built as a single-page application (HTmL file, no server) and saves data locally, not allowing ???"). However, the second issue can probably be solved via https://github.com/Arlen22/TiddlyServer and other tools http://setup.tiddlyspot.com/

Comment: Still, for such questions I suggest your to post at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/tiddlywiki instead

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your TW5 html in a WebDAV share. Different operating systems have methods of creating and authenticating users.

A generic solution if you have Python is the [wsgidav](https://github.com/mar10/wsgidav) module. E.g. see:

```
$ pip install wsgidav cheroot
$ wsgidav --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8080 --root=/tmp
WARNING: share '/' will allow anonymous access.
Running WsgiDAV/2.2.2 Cheroot/5.5.0 Python/3.4.2
Serving on http://0.0.0.0:8080 ...
```

TW5 will automatically detect that it can write itself back to the web location. Username selection and versioning are things that you'll have to use plugins for, or tweak by hand.

Answer (score 0):

To counter your point 2

you can run TiddlyWiki on node.js see: [enter link description here](https://tiddlywiki.com/#Installing%20TiddlyWiki%20on%20Node.js)

I do it myself

It also have the concept of a draft version of each page your are currently editing

but I still have to use svn or git client to keep a history of all versions of each tiddler